# Clone a remote repository to github without downloading on your PC

Tags: git, github, git-clone

There is a remote repository (not hosted on github) that I would like to clone to github. Is it possible for me to clone it to github directly without making a clone of it on my computer. If yes, How can I do this?

Comment: Can you push from the remote repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get an existing repository onto GitHub is to either:

1. Fork a repository that is already on GitHub, or
2. Create a new repository on GitHub and `git push` your repository to it (instructions from GitHub [here](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-an-external-git-repository)).

Comment: you might want to make it explicitly clear that what OP wants (create non-fork repo with contents without pushing -- aka "import external repo") is *not possible* on github

Comment: I think your comment takes care of that nicely :). Thanks!

Comment: I also agree with @NevikRehnel . Your answer include everything but what is asked. Anyway, I'll mark his comment as accepted comment. :)